# creating tde template with element present at multiple places in xml

Tags: xml, marklogic

I am working on TDE using MarkLogic. I have a specific scenario that I need to pull city that is available at different levels in XML. The city value has to go to the same column value not a tab delimited or anything if there are multiple values, but has to be treated as another row for a person/name i.e John Doe.

Below is the data I am using:

```
let $template= 
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde>
<context>/data/person/address</context>
<rows>
<row>
<schema-name>test</schema-name>
<view-name>data</view-name>
<columns>
<column>
<name>address</name>
<scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
<val>/city</val>
</column>
</columns>
</row>
</rows>
</template>
```

Data I am using is below:

```
<data>
    <person>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>30</age>
        <address>
            <city>New York</city>
            <country>USA</country>
        </address>
    </person>
    <employee>     
        <education>graduated</education>
        <address>
            <city>London</city>
            <country>UK</country>
        </address>
    </employee>
</data>
```

If I query my tde I should get below output

| name | age | education | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 30 | null | New York |
| John Doe | 30 | graduated | London |

Comment: Using your example data, please show us what the expected output is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the context to be `/data/*`, which would match on either `/data/person` or `/data/education`, or you could also match on `/data/*/address`.

With the context on the repeating items that you want to create rows from, you can then use relative XPaths to select the values for the other columns.

Since education will only be present for the `employee` and not the `person` you need to mark that column as `nullable`.

A complete example:

```
let $data :=
<data>
    <person>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <age>30</age>
        <address>
            <city>New York</city>
            <country>USA</country>
        </address>
    </person>
    <employee>     
        <education>graduated</education>
        <address>
            <city>London</city>
            <country>UK</country>
        </address>
    </employee>
</data>

let $template := 
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/data/*</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>test</schema-name>
      <view-name>data</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>name</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>../person/name</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>age</name>
          <scalar-type>int</scalar-type>
          <val>../person/age</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>education</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>education</val>
          <nullable>true</nullable>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>city</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>address/city</val>
          <nullable>true</nullable>
        </column>
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>

return 
  tde:node-data-extract($data, $template)
```

Comment: Yes, this is going to solve a part of my problem. Thank you